# R データの基準化

Tags: r

こんにちは。
Rで読み込んだcsvデータの標準化をしたいのですが、「Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric」というエラーが表示されます。sapply(d,mode)で確認しても（dにread.tableで読み込んだデータを入れています）、すべてのデータがnumericであると表示されていますし、なぜこのエラーが出るかわかりません。
解決策を教えてもらえないでしょうか？

Comment: 状況がよく分からないのですが、この記事 [RDA, Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric, when data is numeric?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409561/rda-error-in-colmeansx-na-rm-true-x-must-be-numeric-when-data-is-nume) が参考になるかも知れません。

Comment: `dput(x)`の結果をここにおきなさい

Answer (score 1):

コメントのリンク先にあるように，`mode()` ではなく `class()` もしくは `is.numeric()` で`numeric` かどうかを判定してみてください

Answer (score 0):

dにread.tableで読み込んだデータの、一コマ目（row1, column1)に文字が入っていたら、そこを空白にしてみてはいかがでしょうか？